# How can I check the last set of packages updated with DNF?

Tags: fedora, dnf

Is there a way to list the packages that were updated with `$ sudo dnf --refresh upgrade` from the command line? I cannot seem to find any suitable option in the `man` page for DNF.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
dnf history
```

Using the DNF transaction ID from the list, details can be obtained with:

```
dnf history info N
```

where `N` is a transaction ID.

Transaction roll-back can also be done with `dnf history`. See the manpages for more and also [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/latest/system-administrators-guide/package-management/DNF/) particularly the section titled "Working with Transaction History"

Comment: Perfect! Just what I need.